# Evanescent Field

Tags: electromagnetism, optics, boundary-conditions

I have a few basic questions regarding evanescent field.Are they produced only if there is a Total Internal Reflection? Or just a boundary change is enough for producing evanescent field? Also why is it necessary to have a boundary change for producing evanescent wave?